# Surveys/Important papers in Explainability for LLM?

Tags: explainable-ai, large-language-models

I'm interested in the topic of Explainability for LLM: the attempts to find some higher understandable structures inside the LLMs or, to put it simply (though may be not completely correctly), the attempts to understand how LLMs "think".

Would anybody please recommend where to start?
I'm both interested in foundational papers at this topic and in important latest research.

The great survey or a curated list of papers would be wonderful, although I'm not sure they exist give the speed the field is moving with.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you asked *Large* Language Models specifically? Are you interested only in the Sequence Generation task or also in classification and other tasks?

Answer (score 1):

As you have already mentioned, it's a rapidly evolving research area. These can be the first steps in hunting for foundations.

1. https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.06223
2. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0950705123000230